# php pick data from web and show it in div

Tags: php, html

i have a div and also on same page i have some data which is show on web page i just want data show on div how can i do this? i am very very new in php .thanks here is the php file.

```
    <?php
    define('HOST','xxxxxxxxxxx');
    define('USER','xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    define('PASS','xxxxxxxx');
    define('DB','androidapi2');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

    $sql = "select * from users WHERE status = 1";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array(
         //  'id'=>$row[0],
          'email'=>$row[3], 
    ));
    } 
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>

    <html>
<head>

<title>DIC ChatBox Beta 1</title>
<style>
#usersOnLine { 
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    color:black;
    border: 3px teal solid;
    height: 525px;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}

.container{
    width:970px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
</div>
<h2> all contacts</h2>
<div id="usersOnLine">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the div id usersonline where i want all data show . how to made it.

Comment: You can place your PHP code into the div and output the rows directly instead of building a large array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `json_encode(array("result"=>$result));`, directly use `$result`

```
<div id="usersOnLine">
<?php
foreach($result as $key => $val)
{
    echo $val['email'];
    echo "<br>";
}
 ?>
</div>
```

**If you want to use it on another page**

Creating New Session In php file

```
<?php
session_start(); ///at the top of this file 

///after your query and creating array
$_SESSION["result"]= $result;////set $result in session
?>
```

Getting Session on another page

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["result"]))
{
   $result = $_SESSION["result"];
   ///your foreach loop to print data 
}
?>
```

***[READ SESSION DOCUMENTAION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)***

Comment: i have use json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); it because this php file link with android app

Comment: if you are on same page then, `$result` only will work for you

Comment: I've changed nothing ... just use this code and see

Comment: if i have div on other page and this php code is on other page then how can i access data to show in div

Comment: then you can use php session and cookie to set the data and get on any page you want....

Comment: will you tell me please with code ?? for example this is my php code in question and html code is on the other page how can i send data to that page?

Comment: how to know that where we send this session i mean where i send this result that page name??

Comment: use `header('Location: page2.php');` after setting session  for redirecting on another page, then on page2.php ypu can get sesion  [read header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: i just want it does not show me on web page but it working as it is work